# How do you add information text to a Drupal 7 form?

Tags: forms

I have this:

```
$form['rate_the_room']['room_rating'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'How would you rate the room you stayed in?',
  '#options' => array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5),
  '#default_value' => isset($values['room_rating']) ? $values['room_rating'] : NULL,
);

$form['next'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Next')
);
return $form;
```

This will produce a radio button block where you can select the rating for a room and then a submit button right after it. I want to be able to add a block of text inbetween these two elements. That block should be:

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

Is this possible or would I have to somehow make it part of the actual fields?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405386/adding-text-just-text-to-a-form-in-drupal-7/8405715#8405715) or something more complicated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add plain text to forms, you use `#markup`- see the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute).

```
$form['rate_the_room']['hello'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<div id="test">Hello</div>',
);
```